# TypeScript: type narrowing: assert not undefined and hence exclude from type

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

Both of these lines complain with error "Object possibly undefined" on `_e[k]`:

```js
obj[k] = typeof _e[k] === "undefined" ? "" : _e[k].toString();
obj[k] = _e[k] === undefined ? "" : _e[k].toString();
```

`_e[k]` is a union of many types, therefore a manual type cast is not applicable. How do I get rid of the error?

**update**:
So in a more general manner my question can be phrased as: is there a way to narrow the type of a variable by checking against specific types which should be excluded?

minimal example:

```js
class test {
    a!: string;
    b?: number;
}
const t: test = { a: "hi", b: 2 };
for (const k of Object.keys(t) as Array<keyof test>) {
    console.log(t[k] == undefined ? "LOL" : t[k].toString());
}
```

Comment: `obj[k] = _e[k]?.toString() || '';` doesn't work?

Comment: hm. dunno, using TS3.5, so no ?. available

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  There are all kinds of ways to proceed but it would be nice to test them against at least a toy version of your use case before I feel confident answering.  The easiest thing to suggest: assign `const ek = _e[k]` and then do your checks against `ek` instead of `e[k]`; I expect the compiler will correctly exclude `undefined` from the union after that.  But I can't test it myself so ‍♂️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a longstanding bug/issue whereby TypeScript does not perform [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to narrow the type of a property if the property key is a variable: [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); it wasn't addressed because the fix imposed a large performance penalty.  In your case that means type guard checks on `_e[k]` will not affect subsequent uses of `_e[k]`.

My recommended workaround for this is to assign your index-accessed property to a new variable and check against that:

```
const ek = _e[k]; // new variable
obj[k] = typeof ek === "undefined" ? "" : ek.toString(); // no error now
```

The new variable `ek` gets normal control-flow type analysis applied, and your type guard works.

Other possibilities for different use cases:

- if you've already checked against `undefined` and `null` but the compiler can't figure it out, the easiest change is to use the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

  ```
  obj[k] = typeof _e[k] === "undefined" ? "" : _e[k]!.toString(); // non-null assertion
  ```
- You could refactor your type-exclusion code into its own self-contained expression so that you never have to re-check the original value.  For example:

  ```
  obj[k] = (_e[k] || "").toString(); // refactor
  ```

  That particular code only works the only [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values `_e[k]` can have are `undefined` and `""`. If `_e[k]` could be `0` then that would give a different result.  In general you can make a new function to do whatever you want:

  ```
  function defined<T, U>(x: T | undefined, dflt: U): T | U {
      return typeof x !== "undefined" ? x : dflt;
  }
  obj[k] = defined(_e[k], "").toString(); // refactor 2
  ```

Okay, hope one of those helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gfRALngG8BYAKHgvgG0BrAzGASxQHMBdApAIwCtwsAPvACuKUADNmIYPCEphAWy4gYs+A2YsA3GQC+ZUJFgJk6LHXUYmrHaUPQ4iVJnjceBQtQsbWHS9ZZ4fVIyAHpQ+AAFJDQ0Ri4IAE8RMRBJVJkVGCQYNAA6AvhmUAAPeCgwMBBY+AAHbNqVDEZq+GBUAHIsFFhsgHd4MIiACwwMWrQ8cJZGDGHhLjzkBVCFRjBstCRxDFCAFUTGgGUNxlrdxljhatCARgAGAFYAZnuyN1o2eABeeAxDkDbHAgT4-b6-ABEogkUmAEPgAH54BD4QRcJ88hgkEcrJoABQASlsHxoX1+6NJYN+0LSsMRyNRwIxWJxAUJtiG8GULj6ORosCQ0Nc4ngAGIHi83qRTC4QDQfkzScTeKDfv9GkC5VTkTT0tJ4UiUfACHLMdjcax2WROUg5ioiqAoGhraQSWS-gCgRSyeCdak9XD6Ua0SDSQBCM2s-FE+DheAoVAAWnkEAg5ViTUYqBdboVeO9siEKIJkYtLHZsYicHEFSxMBd4lEYGaqDatJQ0gAPHsADTwACqAD48SUCHs1LrYX3gOIIBgCP2CWO1P2iGRKPA4BhhDAUB6NSKymHfVD-bCDfAygQZ3PbMFc78YR3gPnQ2w+8XS2yY3Hq7WcmKABMQA)

Comment: Added a minimal example. For TS3.8 the `?.` works well, was to be expected.
For TS3.5 using a separate const does it - thanks also for the explanation of why. I didn't think about it but it makes sense.
I thought of the `|| ""` solution (I use it a lot in other cases..) but doesn't work for me in this case. As you point out it evaluates falsey, so `false` wouldn't become `"false"` etc.

Comment: What a mystery this would have been without your clearly explained and documented answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, a (rather hacky) workaround that is OK for my use case (but would not in many other scenarios) is this:

```js
obj[k] = _e[k] === undefined ? "" : String(_e[k]);
```

still interested in (better) suggestions that would work in the more general case (see question update)