# Why is a property with a null value considered an "implicit any"?

Tags: typescript

I can have a simple object like:

```
const wut = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 123,
  baz: { a: 'b' },
  lol: null
};
```

And typescript is fine with all of that, EXCEPT the lol property being assigned to null:

```
error TS7018: Object literal's property 'lol' implicitly has an 'any' type.

         lol: null
           ~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is this?  I am having to do:

```
  ...
  lol: null as null
};
```

Which seems incredibly silly.

*** EDIT ***

As some pointed out, I had turned off strictNullChecks because some code I have does:

```
 public static listeners: { [ index in Event ]?: KeyMapping } = {};

...

 static register (event: Event, key: KeyCode, callback: () => void, bubble = true) {
     if (!service.listeners[event]) { service.listeners[event] = {}; }
     if (!service.listeners[event][key]) { service.listeners[event][key] = {}; }
     ...
```

And typescript spews nonsense:

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

52     if (!service.listeners[event][key]) { service.listeners[event][key] = {}; }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As this makes absolutely no sense!  That object is prevented from being undefined by doing:

```
if (!service.listeners[event]) { service.listeners[event] = {}; }
```

So yeah this file had billions of stupid errors involving accessing nested object properties `obj[X][Y][Z]`, so I turned off that strict null check because it was driving me crazy.

If anyone can explain how on earth that is possibly undefined and how I should re-write something like the above, I am all eyes.

*** UPDATE AGAIN ***
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgQQApIJIDkDiMC8MDeAUDDAMoASqAYgCoBcMAjAGwA0xZSCAwgKIMBmAEzsSCAEriA8gHUA+gBletQQHZRMCdPnjUmcvRgCAnBt6luyfjCGrCAXxgBDCDFCQoAbkKEoATwAHAFMYAGkgv24QABMQvH9gkAAzeGQ0LABtAGsI5JgEoLzEFAxMAF1vQgBLMCgggCckp2AQhSroILAGgg4Qetj6hjAAVwBbACMG7xJgJwAbOfHmrIYACgBKXAA+GAA3ECro6Zhx4fHxuaCGcZAQS6cwb3sfd2gw3gBNABFZdFwYADkOT80RAAHcwADvK9YKFPgBVJAkf5AiLDAJQ3yBEJwPy8XadWDxbF5OHfX4wAA++RJKTJiO8BRg8PhqC+cCcAQCNQA5v98DAMjAarEAB4MaD1XkwMoMNodLr1GDPJnhPwcrnS-mC4VgMW6sIRKKxGUAfgYLLZGu5YD59mh4Dec3adUVEAYAqFIqCooNuPxhLNDDV1uljjw+HtL0dsCc0Wi8td3TwqyCBNqDH96agrBgwODRpiQU2OB2RBIVRSqwAhM6FQ0IBk04SypsBXWk-VG83amV+fblRxKzAax3Og2m9mytkIq2CDAx27Jy2Z34+xGB89nkA

Comment: thats a quirk of the strong typing system within ts

Comment: Oof, why are you using `--noImplicitAny` but *not* using `--strictNullChecks`?  Or just `--strict`?  This problem should go away if you use `--strict`, since `lol` will have the `null` type.  Otherwise maybe turn off `--noImplicitAny`?

Comment: It's funny, I don't even see any issues mentioning this in GitHub. I'm guessing that almost nobody uses `--noImplicitAny` without also using `--strictNullChecks`, or at least so few people do that issues that crop up there don't get reported very often.  My general advice: use `--strict` unless you have a very good reason not to, since `--strict` is used much more widely and any problems you have are likely encountered by others somewhere.  Would you like me to write any of this up as an answer?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz I updated my question to explain why I turned that off.

Comment: Hmm, this is now two separate questions. One is "Why is a property with a null value considered an 'implicit any'" and one is "how on earth that is possibly undefined and how I should re-write something like the above".  [Which one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) do you want to see answered here?

Comment: Well..  I think the first question is already answered-- Turing off `strictNullChecks` in tsconfig causes (more) dumbness where a property assigned to the value null causes ts to think it has an implicit any.  So I guess the second question, please.  I have edited again to add a link to a playground to illustrate the nonsense.

Comment: I'm hesitant to engage further because I'm worried you'll turn your frustration with TypeScript (e.g., "incredibly silly", "spews nonsense", "billions of stupid errors", "this makes absolutely no sense", "dumbness" etc) on me.  Is it possible you could [edit] the question to turn that down a bit?  I'm not saying you're necessarily wrong in being frustrated, but I don't know that it helps to vent this way.

Comment: sorry... typescript makes me very very very angry, but I promise I will not turn any frustrations on you.

Comment: There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520292/typescript-type-narrowing-assert-not-undefined-and-hence-exclude-from-type)

Comment: thanks @jcalz.  I think I am going to stick with `strictNullChecks: false` and just manually cast any null/undefined properties.

Comment: What if you set `strictNullChecks: true, noUncheckedIndexedAccess: false`?